# Do system calls in x86_64 linux still generate interrupts?

Tags: linux, interrupts

In older versions of linux architecture, system calls would always generate an interrupt during their execution. They would be executed by setting the system call number into %eax and parameters into %ebx, %ecx and so on, followed by issuing the specific interrupt int 0x80. Thus, system calls could be said to be a common cause of software interrupts on a system.

However, on modern architectures of x86_64 there is a specific system call instruction "syscall", which bypasses the need to use interrupt 0x80, and thus, the interrupt descriptor table at all. While I believe the previous method of generating an interrupt for syscall is still supported, the syscall instruction seems to be the way it's done in practice.

Thus, my question is: Is it no longer correct to say that system calls generate interrupts? Would a system call still increment the number seen in the "interrupts" column output of vmstat, for example?

Comment: Are you asking if the current generation of the x86 architecture generates interrupts?  The answer is of course interrupt signals can still generated.  "Is it no longer correct to say that system calls generate interrupts?" - This would be incorrect.

Comment: You need to look at the source of `syscall()` to establish if it is anything other than a wrapper for the interrupt calls.

Comment: @Ramhound no, I am specifically asking if system calls specifically generate interrupts, not if interrupts are generated at all on current generation x86 architecture.

Comment: @AFH, as I understand it there is a new instruction added specifically for syscall at the assembly level which does not use the generic "int" assembly instruction for generating interrupts. I admit I'm not quite sure how to dig deep enough to determine if "syscall" assembly instruction itself is a wrapper, though.

Comment: @arrwags - What makes you think system calls don't generate interrupts?  Provide specific documentation that makes you think this.

Comment: @Ramhound See [here](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) for the `syscall` opcode, which is different from the software interrupt `int` opcode. So in that sense "system calls don't generate interrupts on x86_64": They use a different (faster) way to switch to kernel mode. I have no idea if it counts in `vmstat`, and the expression "generates interrupts" is IMHO bad in the first place.

Comment: @dirkt - Thank you for providing this link. I'm curious if you could expand on your contention with the phrase "generate interrupts". Would it not be correct to previously say an interrupt is generated for a system call? As you mentioned, previously they would generate the opcode "int" for a software interrupt to make a system call, so i felt it was apt to say a system call previously "generated an interrupt".

Comment: Usually *hardware* generates interrupts. An `int` instruction is a *software* interrupt. It is not generated, but executed. So "a system call executes a software interrupt to switch into kernel context" can't be misunderstood. I wasn't actually sure when reading it for the first time if you were talking about hardware interrupts generated during the time the CPU executes the system call, or maybe even something else ...